# How to conditionally assert a type to a variable inside a function based on type of an argument passed to this function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a custom useFetch composable for a Vue app. But even though it is vue I think this question is about typescript mostly.

So basically I'm looking for a way in typescript to conditionally assert a type to a variable inside a function based on type of an argument passed to this function.

I'm new to both typescript and vue so I don't really know if it's feasible to do what i ask. If it is not, any advice on how to restructure this is also welcome.

I need `fetchedData` to be either `Ref<T>` when `defaultValue` (of type T) is passed, or `Ref<T | undefined>` when `defaultValue` is not passed. Here is the code:

useFetch composable (shortened):

```
import type { Ref } from "vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default function useFetch<T>({
    defaultValue,
}: {
    defaultValue?: T;
} = {}) {
    // I need these 'as Ref<something>' type assertions so fetchedData doesn't become
    // Ref<UnwrapRef<something>>.
    // That is vue-specific thing. I probably could
    // use shallowRef instead but i'd like to exhaust all other possibilities first.
    let temp;
    if (defaultValue !== undefined) {
        temp = ref(defaultValue) as Ref<T>;
    } else {
        temp = ref() as Ref<T | undefined>;
    }

    const fetchedData = temp; // Ref<T | undefined>

    // code using this ref

    return {
        fetchedData,
    };
}
```

Usage in a .vue component:

```
import useFetch from "@composables/useFetch";
import type { ICustomInterface } from "@types";
const { fetchedData } = useFetch<ICustomInterface[]>({
    defaultValue: [],
});
fetchedData.value[0]; // ts18048: fetchedData.value is possibly undefined despite passing default value
```

Comment: "I need _foo()_ to return _X_ when passed argument _A_, and _Y_ when passed argument _B_".  This almost always means you want [function overloads.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Does [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/w29d8W) meet your needs? If so I can write an answer for you if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need `foo()` to return `X` when passed argument `A`, and `Y` when passed argument `B`"

This almost always means you want [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

```
// for example
function foo(arg: A): X
function foo(arg: B): Y

function foo(arg: A | B): X | Y {
  if (arg.type === 'a') return { x: true }
  return { y: true }
}
```

---

Your case is only slightly more complicated.

```
export default function useFetch<T>(
  options?: { defaultValue?: undefined }
): { fetchedData: Ref<T | undefined> }

export default function useFetch<T>(
  options: { defaultValue: T }
): { fetchedData: Ref<T> }

export default function useFetch<T>({
    defaultValue,
}: {
    defaultValue?: T;
} = {}) {
    return { fetchedData: ref(defaultValue )}
}
```

The first overload:

```
export default function useFetch<T>(
  options?: { defaultValue?: undefined }
): { fetchedData: Ref<T | undefined> }
```

accepts:

```
useFetch<MyType>()
useFetch<MyType>({})
useFetch<MyType>({ defaultValue: undefined })
```

And returns `Ref<T | undefined>`

---

The second overload:

```
export default function useFetch<T>(
  options: { defaultValue: T }
): { fetchedData: Ref<T> }
```

accepts:

```
useFetch<MyType>({ defaultValue: somethingHere })
```

and returns `Ref<T>`.

---

And lastly your implementation is now very simply:

```
export default function useFetch<T>({ defaultValue }: { defaultValue?: T } = {}) {
    return { fetchedData: ref(defaultValue )}
}
```

---

Which works with a default value:

```
const { fetchedData } = useFetch<{ foo: string }[]>({ defaultValue: [] });
fetchedData.value[0]; // fine
```

And without it might be undefined:

```
const { fetchedData } = useFetch<{ foo: string }[]>();
fetchedData.value[0]; // error as expected
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#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)

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, but what if I don't want to return this variable immediately but rather just assert the type for further usage inside the function? Is this possible?

Comment: I't hard to know what you mean, but you can just do inline type narrowing anywhere. Like this: https://tsplay.dev/mpxqBm. If that's not what you want then it's probably best to ask a new question and explain the details of what you.